# Multiple Js file not working laravel mix for frontend and backend

Tags: laravel

I am mastering my blade template for frontend and backend. But in case of backend some js file not working.

Below Error is showing :

jquery.slimscroll.js:289 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object../resources/assets/admin/js/jquery.slimscroll.js (jquery.slimscroll.js:289)
    at **webpack_require** (jquery.slimscroll.js:20)
    at Object.4 (jquery.slimscroll.js:300)
    at **webpack_require** (jquery.slimscroll.js:20)
    at jquery.slimscroll.js:84
    at jquery.slimscroll.js:87

mix
  /*Frontend assets*/
    .sass('resources/assets/frontend/Sass/style.sass', 'public/assets/frontend/css/style.css')

```
.styles([
    'resources/assets/frontend/css/owl.carousel.css',
    'resources/assets/frontend/css/owl.carousel.min.css',
    'resources/assets/frontend/css/owl.theme.default.min.css'
], 'public/assets/frontend/css/all-owl-carousel.css')

.copyDirectory("resources/assets/frontend/images", "public/assets/frontend/images")

.js([
    "resources/assets/frontend/jquery/jquery.min.js",
    "resources/assets/frontend/mobile-nav/mobile-nav.js",
    "resources/assets/frontend/js/owl.carousel.min.js"
], "public/assets/frontend/js/vendor.js" )
```

/*Admin assets*/
    .sass('resources/assets/admin/scss/style.scss', 'public/assets/admin/css/style.css')

```
.styles([
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/blue-dark.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/blue.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/default-dark.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/default.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/green-dark.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/green.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/megna-dark.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/megna.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/purple-dark.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/purple.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/red-dark.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/colors/red.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/icons/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/icons/themify-icons/themify-icons.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/animate.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/spinners.css',
    'resources/assets/admin/css/style.unminify.css',
], 'public/assets/admin/css/vendor.css')

.copyDirectory("resources/assets/admin/images", "public/assets/admin/images")

.options({ processCssUrls: false })

.js('resources/assets/admin/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js', 'public/assets/admin/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js', 'public/assets/admin/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'public/assets/admin/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/js/jquery.slimscroll.js', 'public/assets/admin/js/jquery.slimscroll.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/js/waves.js', 'public/assets/admin/js/waves.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/js/sidebarmenu.js', 'public/assets/admin/js/sidebarmenu.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/plugins/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js', 'public/assets/admin/plugins/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/js/custom.min.js', 'public/assets/admin/js/custom.min.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/plugins/chartist-js/dist/chartist.min.js', 'public/assets/admin/plugins/chartist-js/dist/chartist.min.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/plugins/echarts/echarts-all.js', 'public/assets/admin/plugins/echarts/echarts-all.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/plugins/toast-master/js/jquery.toast.js', 'public/assets/admin/plugins/toast-master/js/jquery.toast.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/js/dashboard1.js', 'public/assets/admin/js/dashboard1.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/js/toastr.js', 'public/assets/admin/js/toastr.js')
.js('resources/assets/admin/plugins/styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js', 'public/assets/admin/plugins/styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js')
.version();
```

I am not sure it is the right process or not. a guidance will be helpful for me.

Comment: Did you import jQuery in your blade file ?

Comment: Yes i have import the file : <script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>; 
but it is showing error